# Spring mvc 415 unsupported, jackson converter not working

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

My controller :

```
@ResponseBody @RequestMapping(value="/services/subsubsite", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public void subSubsite(@RequestBody SubSubsiteRequest request)
    {


    }
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>



    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>




    <context:component-scan base-package="market"></context:component-scan>




    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />


    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>





</beans>
```

SubSubsiteRequest class :

```
public class SubSubsiteRequest {
    private int subsiteId;

    public int getSubsiteId() {
        return subsiteId;
    }

    public void setSubsiteId(int subsiteId) {
        this.subsiteId = subsiteId;
    }

}
```

When I do the following json request, I get 415 unsupported media error:

```
{ "subsiteId" : "123" }
```

**(My request has "content-type = application/json" and "accept = */*" in its headers)**.

So I am really confused. I am using gradle in my project. And I added jackson libraries in case, although I think spring has them built in. What could be causing this ?

Comment: Just a quick guess - subsiteId is int, but in your request it's string. Can you try `{"subsiteId":123}` instead? I would expect 400 anyway though...

Comment: That would be an incorrect json syntax. Although, I tried it anyway.

Comment: Can you show us how you are sending your request? Post a dump of the raw request, with headers and body.

Comment: Incorrect syntax? Nope... (https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/26703618?&site=stackoverflow), http://www.json.org/